# Different links share a same event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I'm working that time on ASP.NET MVC3 application and i have many links in my view such as

Link1
Link2
Link3
Link4
Link5

I need the above links share same event.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: could you define what an event is to you please?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a client side event. Just add a class to the elements and then in the script assign the elements selecting them by the class. Try to search for the elements with the class from some container (selected by id) to avoid searching in whole DOM.

Code:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("SomeContainerId").getElementsByClassName("Class");
elements.onclick = function() {
    // Do your stuff.
};
```

Replace the "onclick" for the event you want.

Comment: oh, that sort of event. `$("a").click(function(){});`

Comment: $("a").click(function(){}); this code is not working Mr. Luke Duddridge

Comment: He didn't say you try that script. He just didn't know what kind of events were you talking about and with my answer got it. Did my code work for you?